# IE BHO - Handle Button Element Click Event in C++, Why Assertion Fail?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, atl, bho

I'am writing an IE BHO to handle button click Event in C++. 
The Other events handled well, but only for the HTMLButtonElementEvents,
When I click the button, The msgbox can show up, but when i click OK, Debug Assertion Failed in atlcom.h Line 4790. The tip is
    Expression: ((HRESULT)(hr)) = 0
I Opened that file and see the real problem goes in its DispCallFunc function.
Can anybody help me to figure out what's going wrong with my code? Thanks a lot.

The main codes is below:

```
class CMyClass:
// Some base classes
, public IDispEventImpl<1, CMyClass,  &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>
, public IDispEventImpl<2, CMyClass, &DIID_HTMLButtonElementEvents, &LIBID_MSHTML, 4, 0>
{
    typedef IDispEventImpl<1, CMyClass, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1> SinkImplDWebBrowser;
    typedef IDispEventImpl<2, CMyClass, &DIID_HTMLButtonElementEvents, &LIBID_MSHTML, 4, 0> SinkImplHTMLElement;

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CMyClass)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE,     OnDocumentComplete2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2, OnNavigateComplete2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2, OnBeforeNavigate2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(2, DIID_HTMLButtonElementEvents, DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS2_ONCLICK, OnHtmlElementClick2)
    END_SINK_MAP()

    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDocumentComplete2(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
    {
            // ...
            // Finded the button i care that is "CComQIPtr<IHTMLButtonElement> spButton" 
            HRESULT hr = SinkImplHtmlElement::DispEventAdvise(spButton);


    }

    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE  OnHtmlElementClick2(IHTMLElementObj *pElement)
    {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Button Clicked!!"), IDOK);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sinking `HTMLButtonElementEvents`, but are trying to handle `DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS**2**_ONCLICK`. Either sink `HTMLButtonElementEvents2`, or handle `DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS_ONCLICK` (and adjust the handler's signature accordingly).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked :).